# rich:jQuery within ui:composition

Tags: jquery, richfaces

I'm trying to use the rich:faces component rich:jQuery inside a facelet composition..
But im not able to produce any jquery call.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

<ui:define name="body"> 
<h:form id="f"><h:commandLink value="Go" id="ex"/>
            <rich:jQuery selector="ex" query="alert('aw')"></rich:jQuery>
```

---

Another question...how i am going to rewrite this to fall for the number 1 mode..
which is as a one-time query applied immediately or on a document ready event..
Sorry but i am quite confused...can you give the other example for number 1 mode..
Hope this will enlighten me...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do from the example you provided but maybe the following will help:

From the [online documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_jQuery.html):

> The rich:jQuery allows to apply styles and behaviour to DOM objects.

As far as I understand the query attribute contains jQuery functions that can be called for an element. To have an alert on your onclick you can do the following:

```
<h:commandLink value="AW1" id="x1"/>
<rich:jQuery selector="#x1" query="click(function(){alert('test')});" />
```

More from the documentation:

> rich:jQuery can be used in two main modes:
>
> 1. as a one-time query applied immediately or on a document ready event
> 2. as a JavaScript function that can be invoked from the JavaScript code
>
> The mode is chosen with "timing" attribute that has the following
>   options:
>
> 1. immediate — applying a query immediately;
> 2. onload — applying a query when a document is loaded;
> 3. onJScall — applying a query by invoked
>      JavaScript function defined with the "name" attribute.
>
> Definition of the "name" attribute is mandatory when the value of "timing" attribute
>   is "onJScall". If the "name" attribute is defined when "timing" value
>   equals to "immediate" or "onload", the query is applied according to
>   this value, but you still have an opportunity to invoke it by a
>   function name.
>
> The "selector" attribute defines an object or a list of objects. The
>   query is defined with the "query" attribute.

There are quite a few different ways to use this component.

The first mode is as a one-time query applied immediately or on a document ready event. There are examples from the online documentation.

The second mode is where you want a JS function to be called from an event, example taken from the documentation:

```
<h:graphicImage width="50" value="/images/warning.png" onmouseover="enlargePic(this, {pwidth:'60px'})" onmouseout="releasePic(this)"  />
<rich:jQuery name="enlargePic" timing="onJScall" query="animate({width:param.pwidth})" />
<rich:jQuery name="releasePic" timing="onJScall" query="animate({width:'50px'})"/>
```

As you can see the jQuery animate function is defined in the query attribute and will apply to the image component when the mouse hovers over the image.

If you are wanting a JS function to be invoked when someone clicks the link then you don't have to use the rich:jquery component and still use jQuery in your javascript code. JQuery comes with RichFaces. If you are using RF 3.3.3 you will have to use jQuery in no conflict mode: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Finally have a look at the live demo for this component:

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jQuery.jsf;jsessionid=BD9D90829B8C4A9E230203856497FC9C?c=jQuery&tab=usage

**UPDATE**

Based on the example you provided in one of the answers please see how I did it below:

```
<h:commandLink value="AW" id="x" onclick="testaw(this);return false;"/>
<rich:jQuery name="testaw" timing="onJScall"  query="stop().fadeOut('slow')"/>
```

You will notice I removed the selector and the event attributes this is because the example you are trying to do would fall into the second mode (as a JavaScript function that can be invoked from the JavaScript code) that is mentioned in my original answer.

I added the two attributes 'name' and 'timing' that are compulsory when using the jQuery component in this mode.

I also added an onclick event to the link (and made sure to return false as this component will try submit the form and if that happened you wouldn't see the jquery effect).

**UPDATE 2**

As requested below is a working example based on your example using as a one-time query applied on page load:

```
<h:commandLink value="AW2" id="x2"/>
<rich:jQuery selector="#x2" timing="onload" query="stop().fadeOut('slow')" />
```

Another example would be:

```
<h:commandLink value="AW3" id="x3"/>
<rich:jQuery selector="#x3" query="click(function(){jQuery(this).stop().fadeOut('slow')})" />
```

The problem with the above is the form gets submitted. I tried this thinking it would work but it doesn't:

```
<h:commandLink value="AW3" id="x3"/>
<rich:jQuery selector="#x3" query="click(function(e){jQuery(this).stop().fadeOut('slow');e.preventDefault()});" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer..Deeply appreciated...I will further study of your suggestions and implement it...I am still new to Richfaces so i need to further study...:))Thanks..

Comment: I have updated my answer and provided a working example to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much Ross, apology for my mistakes.Thanks a lot it was very helpful.Deeply appreciated.^^,